# ios5.0 - setTitle gives a warning

Tags: ios5, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have these 2 properties that are set in a NSObject

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

And they cause a warning to this bit of code - i Think?? Which are set in a UITableViewController implementation file with that the previous code subclassed to it.

```
[destination1 setTitle:@"Main Title"];
[destination1 setSubtitle:@"Subtitle"];
```

It comes up with the warning:

> 'MyAnnotation' may not respond to 'setTitle:'

I have this feeling I am not far away from the right answer:-) Any Advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your properties are declared `readonly`, so there are no setters available.

Comment: I remove the the readonly and the error went away - thanks for the anwer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so i decided to view some tutorials and this was the best one. It shows you how to create the annotation with the title and subtitle. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=fvhNHvq9aLQ#!

That Tutorial follows on from this tutorial which shows how to create the map and change it from map, satellite and hybrid. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=fvj0ywGUM24

Hope this helps.

Cheers